# Pptp отваливается если прописать iptables nat

Tags: iptables, vpn, nat

Здравствуйте.Настроил на сервере pptpd. Параметры:

```
localip 192.168.10.1remoteip 192.168.10.234-238,192.168.10.245
```

Прописал правило iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Протестировал у друга, на своем ноутбуке с Windows 8, интернет друга. Pptp соединение установилось, интернет раздался и я вышел в интернет с ip сервера.

Дома повторил, со своим интернетом, pptp соединение устанавливалось и сразу отваливалось. Методом долгих проб и ошибок обнаружил что соединение pptp отваливается сразу после добавления правила iptables указанного выше. Поиск в интернете ничего не дал.

Если у кого нибудь есть какие нибудь соображения, подскажите, куда копать? Если нужны конфиги или логи, скажите какие, выложу. Заранее спасибо.

**UPD.** Только что протестировал на работе. Работает. Как провайдер интернета может влиять на установление pptp соединения? Может ли быть дело в роутере? У друга и на работе стоит MicroTik, у меня дома WNR612.\

**UPD.** Адреса, как я понял, не пересекаются, привожу ifconfig сервера:

```
root@li522-223:~# ifconfigeth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:ae:4a:71          inet addr:176.58.120.223  Bcast:176.58.120.255  Mask:255.255.255.0          inet6 addr: 2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:feae:4a71/64 Scope:Global          inet6 addr: fe80::f03c:91ff:feae:4a71/64 Scope:Link          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1          RX packets:1382445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:1296869 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000          RX bytes:828754041 (790.3 MiB)  TX bytes:1036590841 (988.5 MiB)          Interrupt:76lo        Link encap:Local Loopback          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1          RX packets:122697 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:122697 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0          RX bytes:79353340 (75.6 MiB)  TX bytes:79353340 (75.6 MiB)ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol          inet addr:192.168.10.1  P-t-P:192.168.10.234  Mask:255.255.255.255          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1396  Metric:1          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3          RX bytes:284 (284.0 B)  TX bytes:110 (110.0 B)
```

Comment: А адресация случаем не пересекается? Не совпадают локальные ip  с remouteip  в pptpd ?

Comment: ... в роутере

Comment: Пятак, ну конечно же! 192.168... - только слепой не увидит, а у него там тоннель прокинут!

Answer (score 1):

Дык, вы же чего делаете-то? Вы пытаетесь роутить внутренние адреса провайдера! А он вам этого не даст, естественно! Поскольку у вас внешний тоннель прокинут, вот его роутить и надо! А лучше - оставьте, как провайдер дал, там тоже не дураки сидят!

Comment: Провайдер не причем, у меня есть сервер в Другой стране. Задача пробросить тоннель до сервера и получить интернет от лица сервера. Проблема в последнем пункте.